# python pandas partial string match

Tags: python, string, pandas, match

I created a dataframe df where I have a column with the following values:

```
category
20150115_Holiday_HK_Misc
20150115_Holiday_SG_Misc
20140116_DE_ProductFocus
20140116_UK_ProductFocus
```

I want to create 3 new columns

```
category                  |           A              |  B  |       C     
20150115_Holiday_HK_Misc     20150115_Holiday_Misc     HK    Holiday_Misc 
20150115_Holiday_SG_Misc     20150115_Holiday_Misc     SG    Holiday_Misc
20140116_DE_ProductFocus     20140116_ProductFocus     DE    ProductFocus
20140116_UK_ProductFocus     20140116_ProductFocus     UK    ProductFocus
```

In column A, I want to take out "_HK" - I think I need to manually code this, but this is fine, I have the list of all country codes

In column B, it's that very country code

Column C, is column A without the date in the beginning

I am trying something like this, but not getting far.

```
 df['B'] = np.where([df['category'].str.contains("HK")==True], 'HK', 'Not Specified')
```

Thank you

Comment: I'm thinking about some string methods like `.split()` for example

Comment: Except your strings aren't all structured the same way, so it doesn't get you exactly where you want to be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [Series.str.extract()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) method:

```
# remove two characters (Country Code) surrounded by '_'
df['A'] = df.category.str.replace(r'_\w{2}_', '_')
# extract two characters (Country Code) surrounded by '_' 
df['B'] = df.category.str.extract(r'_(\w{2})_', expand=False)
df['C'] = df.A.str.extract(r'\d+_(.*)', expand=False)
```

Result:

```
In [148]: df
Out[148]:
                   category                      A   B             C
0  20150115_Holiday_HK_Misc  20150115_Holiday_Misc  HK  Holiday_Misc
1  20150115_Holiday_SG_Misc  20150115_Holiday_Misc  SG  Holiday_Misc
2  20140116_DE_ProductFocus  20140116_ProductFocus  DE  ProductFocus
3  20140116_UK_ProductFocus  20140116_ProductFocus  UK  ProductFocus
```

Comment: Using column A.extract  for C is quite smart. Makes the regex much more readable.

Comment: @MaxU Thank you so much! :)

Comment: It looks beautiful :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use regex and apply

```
import re
df['A'] = df.category.apply(lambda x:re.sub(r'(.*)_(\w\w)_(.*)', r'\1_\3', x))
df['B'] = df.category.apply(lambda x:re.sub(r'(.*)_(\w\w)_(.*)', r'\2', x))
df['C'] = df.A.apply(lambda x:re.sub(r'(\d+)_(.*)', r'\2', x))
```

Result

```
                   category                      A   B             C
0  20150115_Holiday_HK_Misc  20150115_Holiday_Misc  HK  Holiday_Misc
1  20150115_Holiday_SG_Misc  20150115_Holiday_Misc  SG  Holiday_Misc
2  20140116_DE_ProductFocus  20140116_ProductFocus  DE  ProductFocus
3  20140116_UK_ProductFocus  20140116_ProductFocus  UK  ProductFocus
```